# How to move to slide in swiper.js and react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm using [swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api) library in my react app. I want to use slideTo method form swiper API but I don't know how can I do that.

[Link to not working demo from swiper website](https://codesandbox.io/s/bxcmt?file=/src/App.js)

My code

```js
const swiperRef = useRef(null)
useEffect(() => {
  //...some logic
  //if() {
    swiperRef.current.slideTo(0);
  //}
}

return(
  <Swiper pagination={true} navigation={true} ref={swiperRef}>
)
```

`TypeError: swiperRef.current.slideTo is not a function`

Answer (score 11):

replace

```
swiperRef.current.slideTo(0);
```

with

```
swiperRef.current.swiper.slideTo(0);
```

`swiperRef.current` is just referencing to the HTML element which does not contain the js function slideTo().

Answer (score 8):

1. Add onSwiper to Swiper component

```js
<Swiper
  pagination={true}
  navigation={true}
  onSwiper={(swiper) => setSwiper(swiper)}
>
```

2. Add state from swiper

```js
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState<Swiper>();
```

3. Call this part of code

```js
  swiper.slideTo(0, 500); // pass speed as a second parameter
```